# Can't execute custom logic in finally block in try-with-resource block

Tags: java-8, try-catch-finally

Java 8

Here classic `try-catch` block.

```
  FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;
            while ((read = iStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                  // some code here
            }
            return totalRead;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(fileName + " failed, got: " + e.toString(), e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.getFD().sync();
                out.close();
            }
}
```

As you can see I do some custom logic in the finally block

```
out.getFD().sync();
```

Nice. It's work fine.

Now I want to replace it by `try-with-resources` block. I try this

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;
            while ((read = iStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                  // som ecode here
            }
            return totalRead;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(fileName + " failed, got: " + e.toString(), e);
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.getFD().sync();
                out.close();
            }
}
```

but get compile error in **finally** block:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable out
```

Comment: Why do you have two `out = new FileOutputStream(file)` in your last code snippet?

Comment: @Holger Sorry, I edited my post

Comment: You don't need to manually call `out.close()` when `out` is the managed resource in a `try`-with-resources block. That is kind of the point of `try`-with-resources. As for `sync`, if you do need to do that for some reason then I suggest keeping a reference to the `FileDescriptor` in a separate variable.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is that you do *not* need to call `close()` as the compiler ensures that it has been called. Since this happens before the `finally` block is executed, you can’t perform other actions on the resource in `finally`, like the sync call.

You can easily verify this

```java
try(Closeable c = () -> System.out.println("close")) {
    throw new IOException("stop here");
}
finally {
    System.out.println("In finally block");
}
```

will print

```
close
In finally block
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: stop here
```

If you really need to perform a sync operation at the end (in most cases: you don’t), you still don’t have to do it manually

```java
try(OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.SYNC,
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    while ((read = iStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        // some code here
    }
    return totalRead;
}
```

I hope, your “some code” is not just a plain copying which you could simply do with [`Files.copy(Path, Path, …)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) or [`Files.copy(InputStream, Path, …)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

You should also consider using `long` for `totalRead`…