# finally block - variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java-8, compiler-errors, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources

Java 8

```
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


private void createFile(final String json) throws IOException {
        final String fileName = getConfigFileName(this.getSomePath());
        GZIPOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".gz"));
            out.write(json.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.finish();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("createFile: IOException while closing resources", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Nice. This work fine.
Now I want to use `try-with-resource`

```
private void createFile(final String json) throws IOException {
    final String fileName = getConfigFileName(this.getSomeFile());
    try (GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".gz"))) {
        out.write(json.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.finish();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("createFile: IOException while closing resources", e);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get error in this line:

```
if (out != null) {
```

Error is:

```
out cannot be resolved
```

I know this error is rise because variable `out` is on `finally` section.
But how I can use `try-with-resources` and execute method `out.finish` ?

Comment: 1) You either have to extract it to a variable out of the try-with-resources block like `GZIPOutputStream out; try ( GZIPOutputStream autoClosedOut = out ) { ... } finally { do-your-out-things }` (the quirks syntax of the try-expression was then fixed in later versions of Java); 2) Or encapsulate the `finish` method into the `close` method so that it could by "auto-finished"; 3) Or, assuming the previous two are general, make sure `GZIPOutputStream` does `finish` on close (must be declared either in JavaDocs on right in the source code to make sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical perspective - a variable declared in the `try` argument isn't available in the `finally` clause, as you've seen. The good news here is that from a function perspective - `finish()` shouldn't be in the `finally` block anyway. `finish` is part of the positive (a.k.a "happy") flow, and should only be called when you're done writing to the stream. In other words, if the `write` operation failed and an exception was thrown, you shouldn't call `finish` anyway.

To make a long story short - move the `finish` call inside the `try` block:

Side note: Since your method throws an `IOException`, there's no reason to catch the exception and rethrow it. You can clean up the code by allowing it to be thrown from the method call directly:

```java
private void createFile(final String json) throws IOException {
    final String fileName = getConfigFileName(this.getSomeFile());
    try (GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".gz"))) {
        out.write(json.getBytes());
        out.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: The other good news: `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` extends `java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream` and the `close()` method of the `DeflaterOutputStream` calls `finish()` internally (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java#L235) - no need to call it explicitly before closing

Comment: @ThomasKläger yes, the OP seems to have a fondness for obsolete finishing operations. He asked basically [the same question a week before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70392578/2711488) with just a different obsolete finishing operation…